# CLion forces files refresh after build, which takes too long

Tags: refresh, delay, clion

When I build a project in CLion, it also refreshes all of my project files (after the build, actually) - and if I have a lot of them, mounted from a remote server via a slow(ish) network, that can take some time. Can I avoid this refresh somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CLion 2020.2 and later, you can tell the app not to have to wait until the refresh is complete to consider the build concluded and to allow you to continue with other work.

To do this:

1. On the menus, choose "Find > Action", then type in "Registry".
2. Choose the Registry action; you've now opened the CLion registry (yes, it exists).
3. Type in: `cidr.asynchronous.refresh.after.build`
4. Check the box on the value column.

Reference: [Here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360007093580-How-to-disable-refreshing-files-after-build).